# How to display two different texts in a Textview after click two buttons

Tags: android, button, input, textview

So I am experimenting with Android Studio.  I am struggling in the part where I want my "Customer1" button to display the customer1 information. And when I click "Customer1" button, It displays the customer2 information in the same `TextView`.

[image]

the code below is my .java code for activity. I need to know why my code is wrong and how to fix it. Thanks

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView t1;
    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    public void onClickListener(View v)
    {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button)
            t1.setText("Customer1");
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button2)
            t1.setText("Custom2");
    }
}
```

Comment: what happened with this ?

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: The problem here is  can't resolve symbol 'v' in                                        public void onClickListener(View v)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pseudo-code:
declare your TextView at the start of your activity

here is the sudo-code to give you an idea

```
public MyActivity implements View.OnClickListener{ //ensure that you impleemnt this!
    TextView tv;

    public void onCreate(){
        setContentView(...);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
        tv.setOnClickListener(this);
        ... // all the other stuff
    }
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1)
            tv.setText("Customer 1");
        .... //do the same for customer 2
    }
}
```

Note: if you are using a Fragment, move the instantiation of tv from onCreate() to onCreateView()

Comment: thanks, but it can't resolve symbol 'v'  in                                                 public void onClickListener(View v)

Comment: I have only written sudo-code. The pattern is basically correct, your implementation of it will look slightly different.

Comment: Check my code, ensure that you implement View.OnClickListener at the start